# How can I remove a MEPLA cabinet door hinge that has no exposed screws?

Tags: kitchens, hinges

Below is an image of the hinge I need to replace. Just can not figure out how to remove it from the door side? [image: MEPLA Hinge]

Comment: looks like they either used glue or pounded it into a slightly undersized hole or both.    Your guess that the screw holes are supposed to be used to hold it in is correct.

Comment: Like Tyson said, those style hinges are typically just pounded in with a hammer. Possibly you can get under it with a flat head screw driver and work it out?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the two screws on the cabinet side, press down the tiny tab pictured at top right above, then twist the hinge to left (CCW) to unlock the hinge from the door.  There should be a plastic plate underneath held by 4 screws.

[image]