# How Would I Remove this Mepla Hinge from the Door portion?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

[image: MeplaHinge]

I don't want to damage the door by prying, so I'm hoping there's some other reasonable option.  This was addressed before, but my hinge is different.

Comment: Is that just a spring-loaded vanity flap covering the screws?

Comment: [This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/102032/43874) appears to be the other one that is being referenced.  Hinges look a little different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that just a spring-loaded vanity flap covering the screws?

Can you get your fingernails or a mud (joint) knife behind here (arrows)?

[image]

Comment: +1, though it might not be a ‘vanity’ flap as much as a ‘lever holding the thing in the cup’ flap

Comment: That was my first thought; however, when I put a thin bladed screwdriver in there, I couldn't seem to easily pop it out; those aren't hinges, they're unthreaded little pins.  I'd considered popping those pins. Thought I'd see if anyone else had removed a similar hinge before I do more damage.  On the broken hinge, at the top screw on the cabinet, the hinge has separated.  I was able to push the pieces together and get it to hold by using a larger screw, but it's only a matter of time and even now the door is mis-aligned, though usable.

Comment: @BruceN Would you consider marking my answer as accepted since it ultimately solved your exact issue?

Comment: Of course.  Being a newbie on this site, I didn't realize I could do that.  FWIW, I replaced the hinge with a replication from Amazon and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @BruceN No sweat. The green checkmark is much appreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that wedging a thin blade screwdriver under the door mount (as shown by the three horizontal arrows) was the way to release these old hinges.  They were of the sort that were hammered in and instead of screw holes underneath the cover, there were two 1/4"x3/8" knobs that went into holes beneath the cover.  Seems like pretty poor design, and a lot more work for the cabinet builder, but these were made over 20 years ago, so perhaps that's how it was done then.  Hopefully the replacements from Amazon will work as well, since that particular door that conceals the wastebasket is opened at least 5x more than any other door in the kitchen.